# react-router for navigating directory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a component in my app that allows the user to navigate a directory which contains sub-directories and files. There is no limit on the number of sub-directories.

I would like to use the URL to indicate position with the sub-directories. For example, take this structure:

```
- dir
-- sub-dir1
---- sub-dir2
------ sub-dir5
-------- image.jpg
---- sub-dir3
---- sub-dir4
```

If someone has navigated to `sub-dir5` then I would like the URL to show:

```
`myapp.com/dir/sub-dir1/sub-dir2/sub-dir5`
```

While I know how to do this if the folder structure was known in advance using `:param` values, I'm not sure about how to tackle setting up the routes when there could be any number of sub-directories.

I'm using `react-router v4`

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this is to create a root route which will accept one (optional) param which is your file system path.

```
<Route exact path='/:path' component={ DirListing } />
```

Then you need to parse it (split by `/`) in your component to make sure it is valid. Once you got your path, you can load file list and show it to a user.

I would go even that far that you don't really need React Router for this, as you are going to end up parsing the routes yourself anyway. React Router makes is a bit easier though.

One last note, make sure you redirect all of the requests back to your react app (or you will end up with server side listing).

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact strict path="/:folderPath+/" component={DirList} />
      <Route path="/:folderPath+/:fileName" component={Detail} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

or otherwise for the rendering part,

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact strict path="/:folderPath+/:fileName" component={Detail} />
      <Route path="/:folderPath+/" component={DirList} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

This takes route name which ends with `/` to `<DirList />` otherwise to `<Detail />`.

`strict` is needed to distinguish whether a path contains ending `/`.

`exact` is required since `strict` allows sub paths. Otherwise a path `some/folder/file.png` can fall into `/:folderPath+/` when it comes to the upper case of the code example, and a path `some/folder/` can fall into `/:folderPath+/:fileName` for the lower case of the example by recognizing
the path with `params: { folderPath: 'some', fileName: 'folder/' }`

as referred in [Route path doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string), [Route path regExp rules](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#one-or-more)

[Route exact and strict doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/strict-bool)